# How to change css href using window.open in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change CSS `href` using `window.open` in JavaScript.

```html
<a class="cssButton" id="Launch" target="_blank" data-baseref="Example/index.html?" href="Example/index.html?" >Launch Example</a>
```

change into

```js
window.open(/* url goes here */);
```

with all attributes in css href above.

Comment: did you mean ?window.open(document.getElementById('Launch').href);

Comment: yes, how can i include <data-baseref="Example/index.html?" href="Example/index.html?">

Comment: how many windows you want to open?as much as attribues endsWith href?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I modified your code snippets to ensure that they are really code snippets and **not** inline code formatting. I also added syntax highlighting to your code snippets. Lastly, I removed the `...` in your second code snippet to just a multiline comment. Please also state what it looks like when it is rendered. Good luck!

Comment: only one, actually 'data-baseref="Example/index.html?"' send data to endpoint and 'href="Example/index.html?"' open a new window.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want in two steps:

**1)** Change your `<a>` element's target to `'new-win'` or any name you want.

```
<a id="Launch" target="new-win" href="Example/index.html?">Launch Example</a>
```

**2)** Create an event listener for the `click` event of the `<a>` element wherein to use `window.open`. As arguments to `window.open`, pass the `href` and the `target` of the `<a>` element.

```js
document.getElementById("Launch").addEventListener("click", function () {
  window.open(this.href, this.target);
});
```